# Construct a midpoint of two parallel lines with only straightedge

Tags: geometry, geometric-construction

Say I have a large plank of wood that I'm trying to cut in half the long way, but I only have a straightedge (no compass). How can I mark the midpoint between the long edges?

(As a note, this isn't a made up scenario. Help!)

Comment: how are you going to cut it? You are not giving me the sense that you have a table saw; if you have a Skilsaw and long straightedge you can do it, but the width of the kerf is important here

Comment: @WillJagy I actually just need to drill some holes in it, but I figured "cut in half" sounded more parabolic

Comment: What do you have in the way of marking instruments? More to the point, what is going through the holes?

Comment: @WillJagy assume a normal pencil. Also a standard electric drill

Comment: sigh. How are you drilling the holes?

Comment: If your straightedge is actually a double straightedge (i.e., something like another plank of wood, as opposed to a piece of string), then you can do a lot of simple but useful constructions: see [here](http://www.gottfriedville.net/mathprob/geom-2edges.html), for instance.

Answer (score 2):

If your straightedge isn't the idealized Euclidean straightedge, but can also be used to measure right angles (like the end of a ruler), draw three edges perpendicular to the two parallel lines. This gives you two rectangles. For each rectangle, draw the two diagonals, find their intersection point (which will be the rectangle center), then draw the line through the two centers.